# Why do I get empty object with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a beginner in **React Functional components** and I trying to get used to with **React Hooks** to understand the logic of Hooks. In my case; I want to get my initial data -which ı'll be showing this on my default dashboard page- from API in method named **getPlants**. From documentations, ı learned that the best practice to send API requests in react hooks is making the API calls in **UseEffect Hook**. So ı call my **getPlants** method in **UseEffect** hook and setting my response data with useState hook which named **setRows**. It sets the state named **row** successfully but after that line, ı can't get any data in my state named **row**, just an empty array. Also in other methods after that, ı can't use **row** value cause ı get empty again. So what should ı do to my row state to get and handle with full data ? Hope its clear to understand.

```
 const [rows, setRows] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {

   getPlants()

 }, [])               //dependency array empty because ı want it to work one time (like compDidMount)

 const getPlants= () =>{
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getPlants',{
       method:'GET',
       headers:{
         'Content-Type':'application/json'
       }
     }).then(res => res.json())
     .then(resultJson => {setRows(resultJson)})    //sets the state named row successfully with response data
     
     console.log(rows)           //gets an empty array
 }
```

Comment: set the state is asynchronous,
you can put `console.log(rows)` outside the function and see the output after the component gets re-rendered

Comment: That's cause `console.log(rows)` gets executed before `setRows(resultJson)`

Comment: also add `.catch()` to check does it output error or not